# ASP.NET JQuery, when disable an input on form submit always call the same action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cshtml

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación con ASP.NET MVC, y quiero deshabilitar un botón cuando el formulario haga submit.
La parte de JQuery para deshabilitar el botón durante el submit funciona correctamente, pero no se por qué siempre llama a la Acción por defecto del controlador en lugar de llamar a la Acción que pertenece al HttpPost.
Aquí dejo el código cshtml:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
<script>
$(function(){
  $("form").submit(e=>{
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop("disable",true)
  })
})
</script>
```

La parte de JQuery funciona correctamente.

Este es mi controller:

```
public class MyController:Controller{
  public ActionResult MyController(ExampleModel model){
    return View(model);
  }
  [HttpPost,ActionName("MyController")]
  public ActionResult FormSubmmit(ExampleModel model){
    //Do some checks
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

Cada vez que pulso sobre el botón, al deshabilitarlo con JQuery en el evento de submit, llama a la acción 'MyController' en lugar de la acción 'FormSubmit', que es el que quiero ejecutar con el botón.
Alguien me podría ayudar con este error?
Si en el evento de submit no modifico el botón todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Por favor traduce la pregunta al espanhol

Comment: Perdona no me había dado cuenta de que estaba en la versión de español

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido encontrar ya una solución a mi problema con la ayuda de [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899883/html-button-not-clickable-without-being-disabled/34026672), el problema era que si deshabilitaba el botón esto cambiaba el metadato de la petición y así hacía que se llamase siempre a una acción errónea.

La solución es simplemente utilizando el método css() de JQuery para cambiar la propiedad "pointer-events" a "none".

```
$('input[type="submit"]').css("pointer-events","none")
```

Answer (score 0):

cuando haces el form le debes de decir a que acción va dirigida

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, null)
```

En tu caso seria

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("FormSubmmit", "My", FormMethod.Post, null)
```

y al controlador quitale ActionName("MyController")

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por contestar! El problema es que en la app que estoy trabajando tienen una lógica un poco diferente, se hace varias acciones que devuelven la misma view, y dividen la view en secciones,  las acciones indican que sección debe aparecer, entonces no llaman a cada acción con un nombre diferente sino que todos usan el mismo. Ahora mismo si no se deshabilita el botón funciona correctamente, pero si lo deshabilito es cuando da este problema